# React Native In-App Purchase - Error: TypeError: right operand of 'in' is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on implementing in-app purchases in a React Native application using the react-native-iap library. I've successfully fetched the subscription details from Google Play Store, but I'm facing an issue when trying to initiate a purchase.

Here's the part of the code that fetches the subscription details:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const subs = await Iap.getSubscriptions([selectedPlan.google_pay_id]);
      if (subs && subs.length > 0) {
        console.log('Subscriptions response: ', subs);
        setGoogleSub(subs[0]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Sentry.captureMessage('Failed to get Google subscriptions', error);
      console.error(error);
    }
  })();
}, [selectedPlan]);

const requestGoogleSubscription = async () => {
  try {
    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log('requestGoogleSubscription: googleSub', googleSub);
    if (googleSub && typeof googleSub === 'object' && googleSub.productId) {
      console.log('requestGoogleSubscription: initiating purchase');
      const purchase = await Iap.requestSubscription(googleSub.productId);
    } else {
      console.warn('No valid Google subscription details available');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Sentry.captureMessage('Failed Google subscription', error);
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
```

The selectedPlan object contains google_pay_id which is the product ID of the subscription in Google Play Store. The googleSub object is the first object from the array of objects returned by Iap.getSubscriptions().

Here's a sample log of the googleSub object:

```
{
  "description": "test123",
  "name": "Weekly Subscription 3",
  "platform": "android",
  "productId": "weekly_subscription_3",
  "productType": "subs",
  "subscriptionOfferDetails": [{
    "basePlanId": "weekly-subscription-3",
    "offerId": null,
    "offerTags": [],
    "offerToken": "Auj",
    "pricingPhases": [{}]
  }],
  "title": "Weekly Subscription 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Iap.requestSubscription(googleSub.productId);
```

It should be:

```
Iap.requestSubscription({sku: googleSub.productId});
```